# Fetching an object to HTML page

Tags: javascript, json, object, fetch

```
fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
    .then(res => {res.json()})
    .then((body) => {
        console.log(body.title);
    })
```

I'm trying to fetch an object of title in this JSON but I don't understand why I always get this error, is it because I'm not running a server?

> index.html:8 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
>       at index.html:8

Comment: `.then(res => res.json())` — if you use `{ }` around the body you need an explicit `return`.

Comment: THANKS SO MucH i thought if you only have one thing in JS it does automatically return but now i understand i just dont need to use the blocks haha. sorry my bad!

Comment: Note this was also the same problem as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59911219/trying-to-fetch-an-object-in-promises